# Verifying Stokes' Theorem for a given field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

a friend of mine asked me for this exercise, but I'm not sure if I'm right.

> For the next vectorial field $A = (2y,-3x,-z^2)$ verify the Stokes' Theorem for the upper hemisphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9$, i.e., find the flux (surface integral) and the closed line integral, which is the circle proyected on plane $xy$. (Hint: The answer is $9\pi$).

**Solution:** The Stokes' Theorem says

$$ \int\int_S\!(\nabla \times F) \cdot \overrightarrow{\eta}\,dS = \oint_C\!(P\,dx + Q\,dy) $$

I just found that $\nabla \times F = (0,0,-1)$, but I got this doubt: the integral I'm solving is

$$ \oint_C(P\,dx + Q\,dy) = \int\int_D\!\left( \dfrac{{\partial}Q}{{\partial}x} - \dfrac{{\partial}P}{{\partial}y} \right)\,dA $$

where $D: x^2 + y^2 =9$, but this integral, using Green's Theorem, is equal to $-45\pi$. Am I doing something wrong? And if I wnat to find the surface integral, how do I find $\overrightarrow{\eta}$?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: $\mathbf{\eta}$ is the unit normal vector, that is, the vector field orthogonal to the surface; in the case of a sphere (or any subset thereof), this will be $\frac{\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|}$ (to visualize this, extend the radius drawn from the center to a point on a sphere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you got $P$ and $Q$ from, Stoke's should read

$$ \iint_S ( \nabla \times F ) \cdot \vec{n} dS = \int_\gamma F \cdot d \vec{r} $$

Thus, since $ \nabla \times F = (0,0,-5)$, we obtain that ( $\vec{n} = \vec{r}/ |r|$, the radius vector)

$$\iint_S ( \nabla \times F ) \cdot \vec{n} dS  = -5\iint_S \frac{z}{r} dS $$

If we switched to spherical coordinates we see that $ z = r \sin \phi$ and

$$ -5 \iint_S \frac{z}{r} dS =-5 \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{\pi /2} \frac{r \sin \phi}{r}r^2 \cos \phi   \, d \phi  \, d \theta = -5 \pi r^2$$

If we use Stoke's, we see that we're along the circle of radius 3

$$  \int_\gamma F \cdot dr = \int_\gamma 2ydx -3 x dy =r^2 \int_0^{2 \pi} \left (-2\sin^2\theta   - 3 \cos^2\theta \right ) d \theta = -5\pi r^2 $$

In both cases we get $-45\pi$ if $r=3$

Comment: I checked this, $\nabla \times F = (0,0,-5)$

Comment: you're right, I made a typo

Comment: Lok, I tried to found $\overrightarrow{\eta}$ in this way:

$$ \overrightarrow{\eta} = \left( -\dfrac{{\partial}z}{{\partial}x},-\dfrac{{\partial}z}{{\partial}y},1 \right) $$

Taking $z = \sqrt{9 - x^2 - y^2}$. Was I wrong doing this?

Comment: $n = ( x,y,z) /r  = \vec{r} / |r|$

Comment: @user115595, the first immediate problem is that your $\mathbf{\eta}$ is not normalized